# Why am I getting "Unpermitted parameter: format"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, parameters

I'm getting these parameters in my Rails controller:

```
Parameters: {"id"=>"238", "user_id"=>1, "group_id"=>43, "title"=>"asdasdasd 1111 ultadas ult asdas", "description"=>"asdssss", "state_id"=>nil, "allow_anonymous_answer"=>false, "initial_message"=>"asdasdsadas", "final_message"=>"dasdasdsad", "poll_pages"=>[{"id"=>382, "poll_id"=>238, "title"=>"Pagina 1", "description"=>"Pagina 1", "position"=>1, "created_at"=>"2016-05-06T14:25:56.795Z", "updated_at"=>"2016-05-06T14:25:56.795Z"}], "poll"=>{"id"=>"238", "user_id"=>1, "group_id"=>43, "title"=>"asdasdasd 1111 ultadas ult asdas", "description"=>"asdssss", "state_id"=>nil, "allow_anonymous_answer"=>false, "initial_message"=>"asdasdsadas", "final_message"=>"dasdasdsad"}}
```

Yet I get this message: `Unpermitted parameter: format`

Even though I'm using:

```
params.permit(:id, :user_id, :title, :description, :state_id, :group_id, :allow_anonymous_answer, :initial_message, :final_message, poll: [:id, :user_id, :title, :description, :state_id, :group_id, :allow_anonymous_answer, :initial_message, :final_message], poll_pages: [:id, :poll_id, :title, :description, :position, :created_at, :updated_at])
```

Comment: can you show your model associations for nested attributes(poll_pages)?

Comment: It, probably, contains requested response format like 'json'. You can inspect the content of params within your controller.

Answer (score 1):

you need to send correct format like:

```
params.require(:MODEL).permit(:id, :user_id, :title, :description, :state_id, :group_id, :allow_anonymous_answer, :initial_message, :final_message, poll_attributes: [:id, :user_id, :title, :description, :state_id, :group_id, :allow_anonymous_answer, :initial_message, :final_message], poll_pages_attributes: [:id, :poll_id, :title, :description, :position, :created_at, :updated_at])
```

And also **_attributes** for the nested attributes in your permit params
:

```
poll_attributes: [:id, :user_id, :title, :description, :state_id, :group_id, :allow_anonymous_answer, :initial_message, :final_message]
```

Comment: This is not correct, the question refers to the `format` parameter that Rails sends when the request has a specific format (ie`.json`).

Answer (score 0):

You need permitte in strong params the "format", it is in form, but can`t save any value until permitte this.

Answer (score 0):

This is because when your request is for a specific format, for instance, `json` (ie: `/some_controller/some_method.json`), Rails sends a `format` param:

```
 #<ActionDispatch::Request:0x000000011b5e3898>, params: {"controller"=>"some_controller", "action"=>"some_method", "format"=>"json"} }
```

There is a global setting that can be set to always permit `format` params. [In Rails 7](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/7-0-stable/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/strong_parameters.rb#L242) looks like:

```rb
config.action_controller.always_permitted_parameters = %w( controller action format )
```

According to the [comments in Rails 6](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/6-0-stable/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/strong_parameters.rb#L223), it's like:

```rb
config.always_permitted_parameters = %w( controller action format )
```

Answer (score -1):

I know this question is old, but I was having a similar problem and found a solution. In addition to what Sunny mentioned, I had to use the "inverse_of" helper method within my two models.